# Is there a way to get current total document counts per user?

Tags: google-drive-api

In the Google Docs portion of the Admin Reports API, there was a num_docs attribute that could be requested. I have a requirement to report the total amount of documents via the API and it appears that the Google Drive portion of the Reports API will only report on added/created/deleted/viewed documents. Has anyone found any way of getting these counts since the Docs portion was deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to know the total amount of Google Documents owned by a user based on some criteria. If my assumption is true you should use [Google Drive Parameters](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/drive). You could use the criteria `num_owned_items_with_visibility_α_β`, where `α` is the [visibility parameter](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/drive#visibility-parameters_1) and `β` indicates the general form as described [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/drive#visibility-parameters), in the method [`CustomerUsageReports.get()`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/customerUsageReports/get?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22date%22%3A%222020-09-02%22%2C%22parameters%22%3A%22drive%3Anum_owned_items_with_visibility_private_added%22%7D). Don't hesitate to ask me anything if you still have doubts.